# How do I do basic authentication in Emacs Lisp?

Tags: authentication, emacs

I'm trying to authenticate to an API using basic authentication. It seems like the code below should work, but it's breaking when I run it in the *scratch* buffer after running it with C-x C-e (says: debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument characterp)).

My code is below. If anyone knows what I need to change to make this work, please let me know! There are basically no complete Emacs Lisp basic authentication examples I could find online, so this would be a huge help.

```
(setq ztoken "areallyfaketokenrandomtokenwithfakechars")
(setq zsite "https://fake.zendesk.com/api/v2/users/1100000011/related.json")

(let ((url-request-method "GET")
  (url-request-extra-headers '(("Content Type" . "application/json")
   ("Authorization" . ,(concat "Basic "
(base64-encode-string
   (concat "joe@fake.com/token" ":" ztoken)))))))    
(condition-case nil
    (url-retrieve-synchronously
     (format zsite))))
```

Comment: How about if we change the single-quote to a backtick?  That way, what is inside the list is capable of being evaluated instead of interpreted literally.  Also, if you have something like `(setq debug-on-error t)` you can get more helpful debugging messages.

Comment: Thank you; I've changed this now. It's now prompting me for a username/password, so that definitely moved this forward.

Answer (score 1):

As lawlist mentions, your code uses a single-quote instead of a back-tick. Below is an alternative approach, that does not use the back-tick/comma. For more information on backquotes: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html#Backquote

```
(let* ((url-request-method "GET")
       (base64 (concat "Basic "
               (base64-encode-string
            (concat "joe@fake.com/token" ":" ztoken))))
       (url-request-extra-headers (list (cons "Content Type" "application/json")
                    (cons "Authorization" base64))))    
  (condition-case nil
      (url-retrieve-synchronously
       (format zsite))))
```

Comment: Please amend your answer to state that the problem experienced by the original poster was that he used a single-quote instead of a back-tick, and clarify that your answer is an alternative approach that does not use the back-tick/comma.  See the relevant section of the Emacs manual relating to using a backquote:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html#Backquote

Comment: @lawlist answer amended

Comment: Thank you! This is very close to working, but I still get prompted for username + password (even though I know I've defined them correctly & in the right format, as shown in my code excerpt). I notice that, in the link below, they propose a similar solution, but I had the same problem - being asked for username/pwd despite submitting it.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597959/how-does-emacs-url-package-handle-authentication

Wondering if there's a way I can suppress that username/pwd prompt, and take that instead from the headers I submit.